# Is Juice WRLD still alive?

Tags: rap

When I went to his Spotify page, I noticed he posted a few songs even after his death. Even he appeared in Fortnite with theories surrounding that he is still alive. Is he still alive?

Comment: Releasing anything still left on the shelf after the death of an artist is the record business's standard way of cashing in - it's the time they sell most.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks. No idea how Fortnite got in contact with him in his grave.

Comment: Have you never heard of an estate?

Comment: Yeah I think so?

Comment: Related: [List of music released posthumously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_music_released_posthumously)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source @Tetsujin

> Releasing anything still left on the shelf after the death of an artist is the record business's standard way of cashing in - it's the time they sell most.